# Load external Excel file

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, jxl

I have a Spring action which should read in an Excel file and access the values contained in the cells. I am using the [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to process the Excel file. I want it to read from an external folder and not from the root of my project. The problem I am having is Spring MVC cannot recognize my file. I get this error almost every time:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

I even tried something like:

```
Resource banner = resourceLoader.getResource("http://howtodoinjava.com/readme.txt");
```

[as seen here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/01/27/how-to-load-external-resources-files-into-spring-context/), and still no luck. My controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="migrateexcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String migrateexcel(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws BiffException, IOException {
   String fileName = httpServletRequest.getParameter("filename");      
   if (! fileName.isEmpty() && fileName!= null) {//just doing this as the logic kicks in from a form
       FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("file:C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/myfolder/test.xlsx");
       File xlsFile = resource.getFile(); 
       String temp = "";
           Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(xlsFile);
           Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
           for(int i =0; i<sheet.getRows(); i++){
               for(int j =0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++){
                   Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j,i);
                   temp = cell.getContents();
                   System.out.println(temp); 
               }
           }
        uiModel.addAttribute("message", "Excel Data migrated successfully"); 
        return "rates/processexcel";
   }else{
        uiModel.addAttribute("message", "Please select a file before submiting"); 
        return "rates/processexcel";            
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it, and it seems like the only problem is the way you reference the file.

This two ways should work (Unless there is some kind of permission problem):

`"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/myfolder/test.xlsx"`

or

`"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\myfolder\\test.xlsx"`

Spring and Spring MVC are actually irrelevant for the question, but the constructors of `FileSystemResource` are expecting the same syntax in a String, or a `java.io.File`.

Comment: I used          FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Toll_Rates_NJ/test.xlsx");
        File xlsFile = resource.getFile();   and i got "Unable to recognize OLE stream" , looking into it now

Comment: Its is the version of the excel file.nothing to do with reading the file. Thanks man!

Comment: I would try to ensure that JXcel is able to read XSLX files. Perhaps you need to convert them to the older XSL format first. -- EDIT. You saw it first. :)

Comment: Yes, I am converting to an earlier version.But its working. I can print out the values.